# Buttons and links in ViewHolders are getting mixed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I'm Developing an App for People to Download Notes...
So there are Two Buttons in each Cardview *Download* and *Share* Buttons
The Download Button and Share Buttons are mixed... I mean.. Sometimes the data of one ViewHolder is used in another.. Sometimes when i click Download Data. is Downloaded from Same View for all Views.

Here is The Code...

```
package com.razorreborn.csebeta;

import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.CookieSyncManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
/**
 *
 * Created by Kiran Anto aka RazorSharp on 2/17/2016.
 * For more Info Contact
 * Kirananto@gmail.com
 * 9495333724
 * All Copyrights Reserved 2016
 *
 */
public class subjectCardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<subjectCardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final Context context;
    private final List<subjectContent> subjectData;
    DownloadManager downloadManager;
    private String downloadFileUrl;
    private long myDownloadReference;
    private String type;

    public subjectCardAdapter(List<subjectContent> subjectData, Context context){
        super();
        //Getting all the notification
        this.subjectData = subjectData;
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_subject, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(v);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final subjectContent subjectContent =  subjectData.get(position);
        holder.Name.setText(subjectContent.getName());
        holder.Description.setText(subjectContent.getDescription());
        holder.Type.setText(subjectContent.getType());
        holder.Uploader.setText(subjectContent.getAuthor());
        holder.Date.setText(subjectContent.getDate());
        holder.Description.setMaxLines(5);
        if(Global.Orientation.equals("Landscape")) {
            holder.Name.setTextSize(20);
            holder.Description.setTextSize(13);
        }
        final String DOWNLOAD_MESSAGE = "Download  " + subjectContent.getName() +" of Subject " + Global.subject + " Notes from Here :  " + downloadFileUrl + "\n And to Download this App : \n\n " + Global.AppShare;
        downloadFileUrl = subjectContent.getDownload_link();
        downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        type = downloadFileUrl.substring(downloadFileUrl.indexOf("Downloads/") + 10, downloadFileUrl.length()).replace("%20","");
        final String path = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath()+"/"+type;
        Log.i("LOGS : ",path);
        File applicationFile = new File (path);
        if(applicationFile.exists()) {
            holder.download.setText(" Open ");
        }
        holder.download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Add Content To download here...!!!
                if (holder.download.getText().equals("Download")) {
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(downloadFileUrl);
                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
                    request.setTitle(subjectContent.getName());
                            request.setDescription(subjectContent.getDescription());
                    request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context.getApplicationContext(),Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,type);
                    myDownloadReference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);

                    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context);
                    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
                    cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
                    /*Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // without this there would be crashing coz we dont call from a activity
                context.startActivity(intent);*/
                } else if(holder.download.getText().equals(" Open ")) {
                    File file = new File (path);
                    Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    target.setDataAndNormalize(Uri.fromFile(file));
                    String[] mimetypes = {"application/pdf","text/plain","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"};
                    target.setType("application/pdf");
                    target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    target.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes);
                    Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open File");
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
                }
        });
        holder.share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Add Content To download here...!!!
                Intent sharingIntent = new     Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, DOWNLOAD_MESSAGE);
                sharingIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                Intent sharevia = new Intent(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
                sharevia.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(sharevia);
            }
        });
        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //TODO implement onClick for the card here..!
                holder.Description.setMaxLines(100);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return subjectData.size();
    }



    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        public final TextView Name;
        public final TextView Description;
        public final TextView Type;
        public final TextView Uploader;
        public final TextView Date;
        public final Button download;
        public final ImageButton share;
        public final CardView cardView= (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_subject);
        //TODO cardview is taken to use it for onClick Events
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            Name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_name);
            Date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.upload_date_blank);
            Uploader = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.uploader_blank);
            Description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_description);
            Type = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_type);
            download = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button);
            share = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sharebutton);


             }   
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have implemented the OnClickListener in ViewHolder. Should you not have the click there?. I don't see the code download.setOnClickListener(this) in ViewHolder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the recyclerview the views are reused. You have to be aware of that otherwise things can get mixed up. When onBindViewHolder is called you have to make sure that **all** the properties in your view are correctly set.

for example

```
if(applicationFile.exists()) {
    holder.download.setText(" Open ");
}
```

the value is not set to "Download" in else branch.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you have your `private String downloadFileUrl;` as a member variable. So when you are referring to it from your onClickListener you are referring to that variable which isn't guaranteed to still be the proper file URL.

The easiest way to solve this is to use `subjectContent.getDownload_link();` in your onClickListener. You generally don't want to refer to member variables from your onClickListener because they will change as new ViewHolders are bound.